# My question was closed as an exact duplicate, even if it was not?

Tags: discussion, support, close-reasons

I asked a question regarding forum software that matches particular parameters over here: [Which free PHP based forum is the easiest to extend or customize?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/28104/14445)

This question might even be useful for future members when they run into the exact same scenario.

But my question was closed as an exact duplicate of: [Which Content Management System (CMS)/Wiki should I use?](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/25745/14445) - which it is not.

Can the respected moderators please consider re-opening my question and putting it back on the front page so it gets some attention?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your question is a subset of the question that yours now points to.  In other words, while your question and "Which Content Management System (CMS) should I use?" are not the same, your question completely fits within the other question and is a large enough part of it that there is no reason for two questions.  Does that help?

Comment: I'm sorry, I still don't think my question is an *exact duplicate* of the wiki question. Nor is it just a subset of the cited question. However, I went through the answer for the catch-all question again, and understand that *what is the best app for my xyz situation* is not the type of questions the members of this site want to answer. So I guess I'll stop whining about it :(

Comment: @adityamenon Our [FAQ](http://webmasters.stackexchange.com/faq) explains the types of questions this site is intended to cover. If you want to poll others' opinions, your question will do better on a forum (like the one you mentioned in your question) or in [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Okay, @danlefree, chat has been mentioned repeatedly :) I will pop in there the next time I face something similar. What times can I expect to see maximum activity over there? US Day or Night?

Comment: @adityamenon Webmasters chat isn't very busy, but I believe that you'll find [StackOverflow chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/) has a [PHP](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/11/php) room that would suit your question.